# How to create Tracking code for webproperty of GA programmatically

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

How to get the Tracking code of the web property inserted to the Google Analytics Programmatically(c#).If we add the property to the GA manually then we can get the tracking code by clicking on "Get Tracking id". But I'm creating the property using c#. But I'm not getting How to get the Tracking Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating the account and web property programmaticly then the response 
[web property response](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties#resource) from [property insert](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert) contains an id field which is the tracking id.

> id string  Web property ID of the form UA-XXXXX-YY.

As for the full javascript snippit.  That is not returned by the API your going to have to create that yourself.